# Anylogic: Lift trucks get stuck before a node

Tags: anylogic

after a long time. I am building a simple model of lift trucks moving some parts. when they reach a specific node as a destination node of a rackStore pick module, they are stuck and do not move any more. I don't know whether the problem roots in my flowchart and the properties of each item of my flowchart or it is because of my network? I think the former is much more probable.

[image: my flowchart]
my flowchart

[image: 1 is rack store where lift trucks starts from, 2 is destination node and star is where lift trucks stop and do not move any more]
1 is rack store where lift trucks starts from, 2 is destination node and star is where lift trucks stop and do not move any more

[image: arrows show problem location in flowchart and in 3d view]
arrows show problem location in flowchart and in 3d view

finally the error is this:
root.rackPick.moveToDest:
An agent was not able to leave the port root.rackPick.moveToDest.out at time 13.698 / date Jan 17, 2021, 12:13:41 AM (current model time is 18.098).
Consider increasing capacities and/or throughputs of the subsequent object(s) or using PULL protocol

I know that it may be very simple error, but I have been away from anyLogic for a long time and need your help even in simple problems. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to increase the capacity of your delay block... the default is one... if you can only have 1 agent in that delay for some reason, then add a queue before the delay.

Your network is fine.